# <tbody> not hiding when a dropdown value changed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, webforms

I have a table and want to hide or show some  group of rows when a drop down value  changes. this page is having a master page Here is my dropdown box

```js
$(function() {
  $("#ddlIncomeAssement").change(function() {
    var status = this.value;

    if (status == "FULLDOCPAYG") {
      $('#FullDocPayg').show();
      $('#FullDocSelf').hide();
      $('#LiteDoc').hide();
      $('#RentalIncome').hide();
    } else if (status == "FULLDOCSELF") {
      $('#FullDocPayg').hide();
      $('#FullDocSelf').show();
      $('#LiteDoc').hide();
      $('#RentalIncome').hide();
    } else if (status == "LITEDOC") {
      $('#FullDocPayg').hide();
      $('#FullDocSelf').show();
      $('#LiteDoc').show();
      $('#RentalIncome').hide();

    } else if (status == "RENTALINCOME") {
      $('#RentalIncome').show();
      $('#FullDocPayg').hide();
      $('#FullDocSelf').show();
      $('#LiteDoc').show();
    }
    // alert(status);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="ddlIncomeAssement">
  <option value="FULLDOCPAYG">FULL DOC-PAYG</option>
  <option value="FULLDOCSELF">FULL DOC- SELF EMPLOYED</option>
  <option value="LITEDOC">LITE DOC</option>
  <option value="RENTALINCOME">RENTAL INCOME VERIFICATION AND ASSEMENT</option>
</select>

<table>
  <tbody id="FullDocPayg">
    <tr>
      <td>FullDocPayg</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tbody id="FullDocSelf">
    <tr>
      <td>FullDocSelf</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tbody id="LiteDoc">
    <tr>
      <td>LiteDoc</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tbody id="RentalIncome">
    <tr>
      <td class="light-blue-background text-center" colspan="4">RENTAL INCOME VERIFICATION AND ASSESSMENT</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="text-left">
      <td class="text-center">6.1</td>
      <td>Confirmation of rental income held using<br /> - Rental statements;<br /> - Lease Agreement;<br /> - 2 x rental estimates (if not currently rented); or<br /> - Valuation Report (if not currently rented)
        <br /> If multiple properties use Rental Calculator and ensure correct allocation to ownership
      </td>

    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Not sure why the tbody is not hiding
Its running in snippet, but not in actual one.  there is a master page . Can that cause an issue for the script to run. While checking  the view source, I cant find the  element

trying [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53182382/hide-asppanel-based-on-drop-down-value) too

Comment: Are you able to made a snippet example with the issue showing?

Comment: It's working perfectly - what's the issue?

Comment: I've edited your question to turn your code into a snippet. I've left the original code intact, however I *did* add sample rows to your `<tbody>` elements. That said, your code works fine. You'll need to edit your question to provide an example that *reproduces* the issue, otherwise it's like trying to ask a mechanic to fix a car with nothing wrong.

Comment: I am not sure what i am missing. its not working in page. Can  the result vary if the page is having a master page

Comment: If is is asp.net and webforms, possibly do to name mangling, check the HTML as rendered to the page by viewing source in the browser.

Comment: In view source, i cant find any of the  variable given in the  script. Its a asp.net Webform @JonP

Comment: What id's do the `tbody's` have when you view source?

Comment: Also check the drop downs rendered ID

Comment: Cant find tbody element. Dropdown rendered looks fine    
 ' <select id="ddlIncomeAssement">
                                    <option value="FULLDOCPAYG">FULL DOC-PAYG</option>
                                    <option value="FULLDOCSELF">FULL DOC- SELF EMPLOYED</option>
                                    <option value="LITEDOC">LITE DOC</option>
                                    <option value="RENTALINCOME">RENTAL INCOME VERIFICATION AND ASSEMENT</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>

Comment: Well there's your problem, if the `tbody` tags aren't there this won't work.

Comment: Why the `tbody` element missing  in the view source. I removed the master page and tried.  but same effect

Comment: This would be a whole new question as we have no idea on how you are generating the table. Ask a fresh question, don't update this one.

Answer (score 0):

You can't just have the tbody alone -- you need to put `<tr><td>` inside them. See example below:

```js
$("#ddlIncomeAssement").change(function () {
    var status = this.value;
    alert(status);

    if (status == "FULLDOCPAYG") {
        $('#FullDocPayg').show();
        $('#FullDocSelf').hide();
        $('#LiteDoc').hide();
        $('#RentalIncome').hide();
    }
    else if (status == "FULLDOCSELF") {
        $('#FullDocPayg').hide();
        $('#FullDocSelf').show();
        $('#LiteDoc').hide();
        $('#RentalIncome').hide();
    }
    else if (status == "LITEDOC") {
        $('#FullDocPayg').hide();
        $('#FullDocSelf').show();
        $('#LiteDoc').show();
        $('#RentalIncome').hide();

    }
    else if (status == "RENTALINCOME") {
        $('#RentalIncome').show();
        $('#FullDocPayg').hide();
        $('#FullDocSelf').show();
        $('#LiteDoc').show();
    }
    // alert(status);
});
```

```css
#FullDocPayg{display:none;}
#FullDocSelf{display:none;}
#LiteDoc{display:none;}
#RentalIncome{display:none;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="ddlIncomeAssement">
  <option value="FULLDOCPAYG">FULL DOC-PAYG</option>
  <option value="FULLDOCSELF">FULL DOC- SELF EMPLOYED</option>
  <option value="LITEDOC">LITE DOC</option>
  <option value="RENTALINCOME">RENTAL INCOME VERIFICATION AND ASSEMENT</option>
</select>

<br>

<table>
  <tbody id="FullDocPayg"><tr><td>This is FullDocPayg</td></tr></tbody>
  <tbody id="FullDocSelf"><tr><td>Full Doc Self</td></tr></tbody>
  <tbody id="LiteDoc"><tr><td>Lite Doc</td></tr></tbody>
  <tbody id="RentalIncome"><tr><td>Rental Income</td></tr></tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Hmmm. If this does turn out to be the cause of the issue, I may have been a bit hasty to try and fix up the question. I added rows and an encapsulating `<table>` to OP's HTML bit, but I assumed they were being overly brief for example's sake :P

Comment: I am not sure what i am missing. its not working in page. Can  the result vary if the page is having a master page

Comment: `tbody` is missing in the view source . why  this happen

Answer (score 0):

I haven't looked into your actual problem, because we can drastically simplify it.

We can use a [data attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes) which contains the elements to show. Hide all the `tbody` elements then show the ones we want.

```js
$(function() {
  $("#ddlIncomeAssement").change(function() {
    $("#target tbody").hide();
    $($(this).children(":selected").data("display")).show();    
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="ddlIncomeAssement">
  <option value="FULLDOCPAYG" data-display="#FullDocPay">FULL DOC-PAYG</option>
  <option value="FULLDOCSELF" data-display="#FullDocSelf">FULL DOC- SELF EMPLOYED</option>
  <option value="LITEDOC" data-display="#FullDocSelf,#LiteDoc">LITE DOC</option>
  <option value="RENTALINCOME" data-display="#FullDocSelf,#LiteDoc,#RentalIncome">RENTAL INCOME VERIFICATION AND ASSEMENT</option>
</select>

<table id="target">
  <tbody id="FullDocPayg">
    <tr>
      <td>FULLDOCPAYG</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tbody id="FullDocSelf">
    <tr>
      <td>FULLDOCSELF</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tbody id="LiteDoc">
    <tr>
      <td>LITEDOC</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tbody id="RentalIncome">
    <tr>
      <td>RENTALINCOME</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: OP's logic seems to be slightly more intricate. For example, selecting "Rental Income" shows *three* of the `<tbody>` items, not just the "Rental Income" one.

Comment: @TylerRoper, yep I just noticed that!

Comment: `tbody` element is missing in the view source. any clue