# Hide Asp:Panel based on drop down value

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have added some asp panels in table to show/hide the panels based on the  drop down value. Am i missing something

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<%@ Page Title="File Quality CheckList" Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="FileQuality.aspx.cs" Inherits="ElectronicCustomerFile.Checklists.FileQuality" Culture="auto" meta:resourcekey="PageResource1" UICulture="auto" %>

  <!DOCTYPE html>

  <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

  <head runat="server">
    <title>File Quality CheckList
    </title>

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" />
    <link href="../Content/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  </head>

  <body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
      <telerik:RadAjaxManager ID="RadAjaxManager1" runat="server">
      </telerik:RadAjaxManager>
      <telerik:RadWindowManager ID="RadWindowManager1" runat="server"></telerik:RadWindowManager>
      <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" />
      <div class="section-container">
        <div class="section-row" id="sec1">
          <div class="section ">
            <div>
              <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="UpdatePanel1">
                <ContentTemplate>
                  <div class="col-xs-6 padded text-center">
                    <h1>File Qualtiy CheckList</h1>
                    <div class="text-center small"><span>MyTest rvices Pvt Ltd</span></div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-xs-6 padded">
                    <div class="row">
                      <div class="col-xs-4" style="padding-bottom: 5px;">
                        <telerik:RadButton ID="btnSave" runat="server" Width="150" CssClass="btn-success" Text="Save Checklist" OnClick="btnSave_Click"></telerik:RadButton>
                      </div>
                      <div class="col-xs-8" style="padding-bottom: 5px; text-align: left;">
                        Last saved by:
                        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblLastModifiedBy" />
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                      <div class="col-xs-4" style="padding-bottom: 5px;"></div>
                      <div class="col-xs-8" style="padding-bottom: 5px; padding-top: 10px;">
                        Send to Verify by:
                        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblSendtoVerifyBy" />
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                      <div class="col-xs-4" style="padding-bottom: 5px;">
                        <telerik:RadButton ID="btnFinalise" runat="server" Width="150" CssClass="btn-success" Text="Finalise Checklist" OnClick="btnFinalise_Click"></telerik:RadButton>
                      </div>
                      <div class="col-xs-8" style="padding-bottom: 5px; text-align: left;">
                        Finalised by:
                        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblFinalisedBy"></asp:Label>
                      </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="row">
                      <div class="col-xs-12 " style="text-align: left;">
                        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblErrorMessage" ForeColor="Red" />
                        <asp:ValidationSummary ID="ValidationSummary1" ValidationGroup="group1" runat="server" ForeColor="Red" />
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </ContentTemplate>
              </asp:UpdatePanel>
              <asp:UpdateProgress runat="server" ID="PageUpdateProgress">
                <ProgressTemplate>
                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-12 text-center">
                      <img src="../Images/Animation.gif" />
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </ProgressTemplate>
              </asp:UpdateProgress>
              <div class="text-center" runat="server">
                <div class="col-xs-12" style="overflow: auto;">
                  <table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-striped" id="tbFileQuality">
                    <tr>

                      <th class="col-xs-1 light-blue-half-strength-background text-center">REF</th>
                      <th class="col-xs-5 light-blue-half-strength-background text-center">ACTION</th>
                      <th class="col-xs-2 light-blue-half-strength-background text-center">Recommender<br /> Yes/No <span style="font-size: 10px; font-weight: normal;">(click to change)</span></th>
                      <th class="col-xs-2 light-blue-half-strength-background  text-center">Approver(s)<br /> Yes/No <span style="font-size: 10px; font-weight: normal;">(click to change)</span>

                      </th>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                      <td class="light-blue-background text-center" colspan="4">INCOME ASSESSMENT</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td colspan="4">
                        <div>
                          <select id="ddlIncomeAssement">
                            <option value="FULLDOCPAYG">FULL DOC-PAYG</option>
                            <option value="FULLDOCSELF">FULL DOC- SELF EMPLOYED</option>
                            <option value="LITEDOC">LITE DOC</option>
                            <option value="RENTALINCOME">RENTAL INCOME VERIFICATION AND ASSEMENT</option>
                          </select>
                        </div>
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                    <asp:Panel ID="FullDocPayg" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static">
                      <tr>
                        <td class="light-blue-background text-center" colspan="4">FULL DOC - PAYG</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr class="text-left">
                        <td class="text-center">4.1</td>
                        <td>One or more of the following held to confirm income:<br /> - payslips;<br /> - PAYG Summary;<br /> - Tax Returns;<br /> - ATO Assessment Notices;<br /> - 3 months bank statements; or
                          <br /> - Employment Letter/Contract
                        </td>
                        <td class="text-center" style="vertical-align: middle">
                          <telerik:RadToggleButton ID="btnToggle41" runat="server" AutoPostBack="False" Font-Size="14px">
                            <ToggleStates>
                              <telerik:ButtonToggleState Text=" " meta:resourcekey="ButtonToggleStateResource16" />
                              <telerik:ButtonToggleState Text="Yes" meta:resourcekey="ButtonToggleStateResource17" />
                              <telerik:ButtonToggleState Text="No" meta:resourcekey="ButtonToggleStateResource18" />

                            </ToggleStates>
                          </telerik:RadToggleButton>
                        </td>
                        <td class="text-center" rowspan="3" style="vertical-align: middle">
                          <telerik:RadToggleButton ID="btnToggle4" runat="server" AutoPostBack="False" Font-Size="14px">
                            <ToggleStates>
                              <telerik:ButtonToggleState Text=" " meta:resourcekey="ButtonToggleStateResource19" />
                              <telerik:ButtonToggleState Text="Yes" meta:resourcekey="ButtonToggleStateResource20" />
                              <telerik:ButtonToggleState Text="No" meta:resourcekey="ButtonToggleStateResource21" />

                            </ToggleStates>
                          </telerik:RadToggleButton>
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr class="text-left">
                        <td class="text-center">4.2</td>
                        <td>Verification documents held:<br /> - ABN Search of Employer; and<br /> - employment verified via Google/White Pages Search.
                        </td>
                        <td class="text-center" style="vertical-align: middle">
                          <telerik:RadToggleButton ID="btnToggle42" runat="server" AutoPostBack="False" Font-Size="14px">
                            <ToggleStates>
                              <telerik:ButtonToggleState Text=" " meta:resourcekey="ButtonToggleStateResource22" />
                              <telerik:ButtonToggleState Text="Yes" meta:resourcekey="ButtonToggleStateResource23" />
                              <telerik:ButtonToggleState Text="No" meta:resourcekey="ButtonToggleStateResource24" />

                            </ToggleStates>
                          </telerik:RadToggleButton>
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr class="text-left">
                        <td class="text-center">4.3</td>
                        <td>Employment verification call completed
                        </td>
                        <td class="text-center" style="vertical-align: middle">
                          <telerik:RadToggleButton ID="btnToggle43" runat="server" AutoPostBack="False" Font-Size="14px">
                            <ToggleStates>
                              <telerik:ButtonToggleState Text=" " meta:resourcekey="ButtonToggleStateResource22" />
                              <telerik:ButtonToggleState Text="Yes" meta:resourcekey="ButtonToggleStateResource23" />
                              <telerik:ButtonToggleState Text="No" meta:resourcekey="ButtonToggleStateResource24" />

                            </ToggleStates>
                          </telerik:RadToggleButton>
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                    </asp:Panel>

                    <asp:Panel ID="FullDocSelf" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static">
                      <tr>
                        <td class="light-blue-background text-center" colspan="4">FULL DOC - SELF EMPLOYED </td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr class="text-left">
                        <td class="text-center">5.1</td>
                        <td>Income confirmation held including:<br /> - 2 years Financial Statements;<br /> - 2 years tax Returns; and
                          <br /> - 2 years Notice of Assessment (for individuals only)<br /> Company search to confirm structure and ownership
                        </td>
                        <td class="text-center" style="vertical-align: middle">
                          <telerik:RadToggleButton ID="btnToggle51" runat="server" AutoPostBack="False" Font-Size="14px">
                            <ToggleStates>
                              <telerik:ButtonToggleState Text=" " meta:resourcekey="ButtonToggleStateResource16" />
                              <telerik:ButtonToggleState Text="Yes" meta:resourcekey="ButtonToggleStateResource17" />
                              <telerik:ButtonToggleState Text="No" meta:resourcekey="ButtonToggleStateResource18" />

                            </ToggleStates>
                          </telerik:RadToggleButton>
                        </td>
                        <td class="text-center" rowspan="3" style="vertical-align: middle">
                          <telerik:RadToggleButton ID="btnToggle5" runat="server" AutoPostBack="False" Font-Size="14px">
                            <ToggleStates>
                              <telerik:ButtonToggleState Text=" " meta:resourcekey="ButtonToggleStateResource19" />
                              <telerik:ButtonToggleState Text="Yes" meta:resourcekey="ButtonToggleStateResource20" />
                              <telerik:ButtonToggleState Text="No" meta:resourcekey="ButtonToggleStateResource21" />

                            </ToggleStates>
                          </telerik:RadToggleButton>
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr class="text-left">
                        <td class="text-center">5.2</td>
                        <td>Financials calculator completed and acceptable income entered into Servicing Calculator
                        </td>
                        <td class="text-center" style="vertical-align: middle">
                          <telerik:RadToggleButton ID="btnToggle52" runat="server" AutoPostBack="False" Font-Size="14px">
                            <ToggleStates>
                              <telerik:ButtonToggleState Text=" " meta:resourcekey="ButtonToggleStateResource22" />
                              <telerik:ButtonToggleState Text="Yes" meta:resourcekey="ButtonToggleStateResource23" />
                              <telerik:ButtonToggleState Text="No" meta:resourcekey="ButtonToggleStateResource24" />
                            </ToggleStates>
                          </telerik:RadToggleButton>
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr class="text-left">
                        <td class="text-center">5.3</td>
                        <td>ABN search of company held on file
                        </td>
                        <td class="text-center" style="vertical-align: middle">
                          <telerik:RadToggleButton ID="btnToggle53" runat="server" AutoPostBack="False" Font-Size="14px">
                            <ToggleStates>
                              <telerik:ButtonToggleState Text=" " meta:resourcekey="ButtonToggleStateResource22" />
                              <telerik:ButtonToggleState Text="Yes" meta:resourcekey="ButtonToggleStateResource23" />
                              <telerik:ButtonToggleState Text="No" meta:resourcekey="ButtonToggleStateResource24" />
                            </ToggleStates>
                          </telerik:RadToggleButton>
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                    </asp:Panel>
                    <asp:Panel ID="LiteDoc" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static">
                      <tr>
                        <td class="light-blue-background text-center" colspan="4">LITE DOC</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr class="text-left">
                        <td class="text-center">5.1</td>
                        <td>Self Employed Borrower Repayment Declaration (SBRD) fully signed,dated and completed
                        </td>
                        <td class="text-center" style="vertical-align: middle">
                          <telerik:RadToggleButton ID="btnToggleLite51" runat="server" AutoPostBack="False" Font-Size="14px">
                            <ToggleStates>
                              <telerik:ButtonToggleState Text=" " meta:resourcekey="ButtonToggleStateResource16" />
                              <telerik:ButtonToggleState Text="Yes" meta:resourcekey="ButtonToggleStateResource17" />
                              <telerik:ButtonToggleState Text="No" meta:resourcekey="ButtonToggleStateResource18" />
                            </ToggleStates>
                          </telerik:RadToggleButton>
                        </td>
                        <td class="text-center" rowspan="5" style="vertical-align: middle">
                          <telerik:RadToggleButton ID="btnToggleLite5" runat="server" AutoPostBack="False" Font-Size="14px">
                            <ToggleStates>
                              <telerik:ButtonToggleState Text=" " meta:resourcekey="ButtonToggleStateResource19" />
                              <telerik:ButtonToggleState Text="Yes" meta:resourcekey="ButtonToggleStateResource20" />
                              <telerik:ButtonToggleState Text="No" meta:resourcekey="ButtonToggleStateResource21" />
                            </ToggleStates>
                          </telerik:RadToggleButton>
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr class="text-left">
                        <td class="text-center">5.2</td>
                        <td>Accountant's Letter held and in right format. Any changes accepted have been explained in CARF Notes or confirmed in Accountant's Interview.
                        </td>
                        <td class="text-center" style="vertical-align: middle">
                          <telerik:RadToggleButton ID="btnToggleLite52" runat="server" AutoPostBack="False" Font-Size="14px">
                            <ToggleStates>
                              <telerik:ButtonToggleState Text=" " meta:resourcekey="ButtonToggleStateResource22" />
                              <telerik:ButtonToggleState Text="Yes" meta:resourcekey="ButtonToggleStateResource23" />
                              <telerik:ButtonToggleState Text="No" meta:resourcekey="ButtonToggleStateResource24" />

                            </ToggleStates>
                          </telerik:RadToggleButton>
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr class="text-left">
                        <td class="text-center">5.3</td>
                        <td>Accountant's interview completed with any concerns or material changes to standard letter discussed with accountants and noted.
                        </td>
                        <td class="text-center" style="vertical-align: middle">
                          <telerik:RadToggleButton ID="btnToggleLite53" runat="server" AutoPostBack="False" Font-Size="14px">
                            <ToggleStates>
                              <telerik:ButtonToggleState Text=" " meta:resourcekey="ButtonToggleStateResource22" />
                              <telerik:ButtonToggleState Text="Yes" meta:resourcekey="ButtonToggleStateResource23" />
                              <telerik:ButtonToggleState Text="No" meta:resourcekey="ButtonToggleStateResource24" />
                            </ToggleStates>
                          </telerik:RadToggleButton>
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr class="text-left">
                        <td class="text-center">5.4</td>
                        <td>All searches held on file and checked to incormation on file:<br /> - ABN search of income source<br /> - ABN search of accountant;<br /> - google / phone search of accountant- phone number used in Interview to match search
                        </td>
                        <td class="text-center" style="vertical-align: middle">
                          <telerik:RadToggleButton ID="btnToggleLite54" runat="server" AutoPostBack="False" Font-Size="14px">
                            <ToggleStates>
                              <telerik:ButtonToggleState Text=" " meta:resourcekey="ButtonToggleStateResource22" />
                              <telerik:ButtonToggleState Text="Yes" meta:resourcekey="ButtonToggleStateResource23" />
                              <telerik:ButtonToggleState Text="No" meta:resourcekey="ButtonToggleStateResource24" />
                            </ToggleStates>
                          </telerik:RadToggleButton>
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr class="text-left">
                        <td class="text-center">5.5</td>
                        <td>If BAS Statements ensure 12 months held; BAS calculator completed & Income aligns with what declared?
                          <br /> Any inconsistencies queried with Applicant/Broker/Accountant-is explanation reasonable? And do we have any evidence to support inconsistency?
                        </td>
                        <td class="text-center" style="vertical-align: middle">
                          <telerik:RadToggleButton ID="btnToggleLite55" runat="server" AutoPostBack="False" Font-Size="14px">
                            <ToggleStates>
                              <telerik:ButtonToggleState Text=" " meta:resourcekey="ButtonToggleStateResource22" />
                              <telerik:ButtonToggleState Text="Yes" meta:resourcekey="ButtonToggleStateResource23" />
                              <telerik:ButtonToggleState Text="No" meta:resourcekey="ButtonToggleStateResource24" />
                            </ToggleStates>
                          </telerik:RadToggleButton>
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                    </asp:Panel>
                    <asp:Panel ID="RentalIncome" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static">
                      <tr>
                        <td class="light-blue-background text-center" colspan="4">RENTAL INCOME VERIFICATION AND ASSESSMENT</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr class="text-left">
                        <td class="text-center">6.1</td>
                        <td>Confirmation of rental income held using<br /> - Rental statements;<br /> - Lease Agreement;<br /> - 2 x rental estimates (if not currently rented); or<br /> - Valuation Report (if not currently rented)
                          <br /> If multiple properties use Rental Calculator and ensure correct allocation to ownership
                        </td>
                        <td class="text-center" style="vertical-align: middle">
                          <telerik:RadToggleButton ID="btnToggle61" runat="server" AutoPostBack="False" Font-Size="14px">
                            <ToggleStates>
                              <telerik:ButtonToggleState Text=" " meta:resourcekey="ButtonToggleStateResource16" />
                              <telerik:ButtonToggleState Text="Yes" meta:resourcekey="ButtonToggleStateResource17" />
                              <telerik:ButtonToggleState Text="No" meta:resourcekey="ButtonToggleStateResource18" />
                            </ToggleStates>
                          </telerik:RadToggleButton>
                        </td>
                        <td class="text-center" style="vertical-align: middle">
                          <telerik:RadToggleButton ID="btnToggle6" runat="server" AutoPostBack="False" Font-Size="14px">
                            <ToggleStates>
                              <telerik:ButtonToggleState Text=" " meta:resourcekey="ButtonToggleStateResource19" />
                              <telerik:ButtonToggleState Text="Yes" meta:resourcekey="ButtonToggleStateResource20" />
                              <telerik:ButtonToggleState Text="No" meta:resourcekey="ButtonToggleStateResource21" />
                            </ToggleStates>
                          </telerik:RadToggleButton>
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                    </asp:Panel>


                  </table>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
    <telerik:RadScriptBlock runat="server">
      <script src="<%= Page.ResolveClientUrl(" ~/Scripts/bootstrap.js ") %>"></script>
      <script src="<%= Page.ResolveClientUrl(" ~/Scripts/respond.js ") %>"></script>
    </telerik:RadScriptBlock>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(function() {
        $("#ddlIncomeAssement").change(function() {
          var status = this.value;

          if (status == "FULLDOCPAYG") {
            $('#FullDocPayg').show();
            $('#FullDocSelf').hide();
            $('#LiteDoc').hide();
            $('#RentalIncome').hide();

          } else if (status == "FULLDOCSELF") {
            $('#FullDocPayg').hide();
            $('#FullDocSelf').show();
            $('#LiteDoc').hide();
            $('#RentalIncome').hide();
          } else if (status == "LITEDOC") {
            $('#FullDocPayg').hide();
            $('#FullDocSelf').hide();
            $('#LiteDoc').show();
            $('#RentalIncome').hide();

          } else if (status == "RENTALINCOME") {
            $('#RentalIncome').show();
            $('#FullDocPayg').hide();
            $('#FullDocSelf').hide();
            $('#LiteDoc').hide();
          }
          // alert(status);
        });
      });
    </script>
  </body>

  </html>
```

The reason i tried with panel is because , i  was trying to use `tbody`, and it failed . [Check this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53165406/tbody-not-hiding-when-a-dropdown-value-changed?noredirect=1#comment93253207_53165406)

Can some one please guide why the panels are not getting hidden. Can't we use panel in table

Comment: tag jQuery as you used jQuery to hide the panel with id `FullDocPayg` with `ddlIncomeAssement`'s changes.. do check your browser console for any errors.

Comment: no error in console

Comment: An `asp:panel` renders a `div` tag, which is not a valid child of `table`